# Loop iteration limit exceeded in synthesis but not in simulation

Tags: verilog, fpga, synthesis

I wrote code in verilog that cycles through active channels.
The idea is to skip channels that are marked by 0 in the activity vector.

I tested the code in a simulator
[screen shot from simulatior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKrE2.png), it works and performs as expected.

When I try to synthesize the code using Synplify Pro, I get an error:
"E  CS162   Loop iteration limit 4000 exceeded - add '// synthesis loop_limit 8000' before the loop construct   test1.v (11)"

The error points to the condition of the loop (`i < 6'b100000`).

Searching for the error in google I found a common mistake in a similar code of having `i` the same length as `channel` which makes the loop to run indefinetly because `11111 + 1 = 00000`.

Also, there is some bug in Xilinx software but i'm not using it.

Any idea why i'm getting this error or why it differs from simulation?
Is there a way to implement this function without a loop?

This is the code:

```
module test1 (
input wire [31:0] activity,
input wire  RESET,
input wire  CLK);

reg [4:0] channel, next_channel;
reg [5:0] i,j;

always @(activity, channel) begin
    next_channel = 5'b0;
    for (i = 6'b0; i < 6'b100000 ; i = i + 6'b1) begin
        j = i + {1'b0, channel} + 6'b1;
        if (j>6'b011111)
            j = j - 6'b100000;
        if (activity[j[4:0]]) begin
            next_channel = j[4:0];
            i = 6'b101111;
        end
    end
end

always @(posedge CLK, negedge RESET) begin
    if (RESET == 1'b0)
        channel = 5'b0;
    else
        channel = next_channel;
end

endmodule
```

Comment: You shouldn't get this error if the loop limit is actually a (<4K) constant. What's the `i = 47` line meant to do? Are you trying to exit the loop early? I think you're confusing the compiler, which thinks (correctly) that you've now got a variable iteration count. I don't think Synplify is smart enough to handle a variable limit. Think hardware - a functioning simulation is no guarantee that you can synthesise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, the number of iterrations is not loop iterations but rather compiling iterations.

The problem is trying to exit the loop in the middle (the `i = 6'b101111` line). This can't be unrolled into a series of commands. Seems that loops only save you from re-typing the same thing over and over and can't do anything more complex.

A possible solution would be to type all the 32 `if...else...if...else...` such that when the first `1` in `activity` is found the condition is met and you don't enter the next `else`. I think it would look like this:

```
always @(activity, channel) begin
    next_channel = 5'b0;
    if (activity[channel + 1])
        next_channel = channel + 1;
    else if (activity[channel + 2])
            next_channel = channel + 2;  
         else if (activity[channel + 3])
                 next_channel = channel + 3; 
              else if (activity[channel + 4])
                      next_channel = channel + 4; 
    .
    .
    .
```

I solved the problem with a flag (as [EML](https://stackoverflow.com/users/785194/eml) suggested). With the flag, the code is unrolled into 32 repetitions of the same code with different `i` and the "stopping" is acheived by changing the flas so that the condition is not met in further repetitions.

The solution code:

```
reg flag;

always @(activity, channel) begin
    next_channel = 5'b0;
    flag = 1;
    for (i = 6'b0; i < 6'b100000 ; i = i + 6'b1) begin
        j = i + {1'b0, channel} + 6'b1;
        if (j>6'b011111)
            j = j - 6'b100000;
        if (activity[j[4:0]] && flag) begin
            next_channel = j[4:0];
            flag = 0;
        end
    end
end
```

This passed synthesis and gives the expected results in simulation.

Comment: right, you should never modify the loop iterator variable  in the middle of the loop, or use any other ways to exit a loop from the  middle. It needs to be fully unrollable at compilation time for synthesis to succeed.

Comment: +1 for fixing it. But note that you're solving this like a programmer - your harwdare  is way too big, and way too slow, and you're relying on the synthesiser to make sense of it. You need to think parallel - look up priority encoders, for starters.

Comment: @EML , I found [this](https://vlsicoding.blogspot.com/2013/10/design-3x8-priority-encoder-in-verilog.html) implementation of a priority encoder and it looks very similar to the solution I suggested with the nested ifs. Do you think this solution is better? Could you please explain how you see that the hardware is smaller and faster?
The module I'm working on is more similar to a round robin arbiter but it needs to skip the inactive channels and I haven't found any implementations on the web.

Comment: @alexander-tarnavsky, I'm wondering what implementation you decided to go with. It seems that the successful use of 'for loops' depends heavily on the synthesis engine. Did you try any other alternative?